# WPF bind fail,when I go to change position of elment about binded Collection 

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, wpf-4.0

```
public ObservableCollection<string> S { get; set; }
```

> S is binded to ListBox Control,switch element of S,bind fail.ListBox Current item is follow:

```
 public string CurrentItem 
    {
        get
        {
            return m_currentitem;
        }
        set
        {
            m_currentitem = value;
            int index = S.IndexOf(value);
            if (index >= 5)
            {
                string s = S[4];
                S[4]= m_currentitem;
                m_currentitem = s;
            }
        }
    }
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding S}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem,Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="5" Loaded="UniformGrid_Loaded"></UniformGrid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: what can way  to resolve problem? thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do and where does the binding fail? I tried your code and got no exception

Comment: Problem is go to click LisBox item which is more than 5 about index,Switch position is success with 4.but I go to click the same item is fail to switch with 4.Bind should be fail.